# Computing jacobian column-wise with Pytorch, and without loop

Tags: python, pytorch

In Pytorch, I have a multi-dimension solution stored on each column of a tensor `u`, and for the training of the PINN I'm developing, I use this function to compute the derivative column-wise.

```py
def dt(self, u, t):
    # return batch_jacobian(u, t)
    N = u.shape[1]
    u_t = [] # initializing the time derivatives
    # for each columns (i), we compute the time derivative ui_t
    for i in range(N):
        ui_t = torch.autograd.grad(u[:, i], t,
                                   grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u[:, i]),
                                   retain_graph=True,
                                   create_graph=True,
                                   allow_unused=True)[0]
        u_t.append(ui_t) # time derivatives are stored in u_t
    u_t = torch.cat(tuple(u_t), dim=1) # we concateneate all the derivatives
    return u_t
```

but it involves a `for` loop that I would like to remove.

In my research about it, I found this [topic](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/computing-batch-jacobian-efficiently/80771) with the same issue, but I wasn't able to fix my code with the proposed solutions.

Here is the definition of the functional that is used for the training of the neural network :

```py
def functional_f(self, t, theta):
    self.A = torch.tensor(theta[:,1:], requires_grad=False).float().to(self.device)
    self.mu = torch.tensor(theta[:,0], requires_grad=False).float().to(self.device)

    u = self.dnn(t)
    u_t = self.dt(u, t)
    ode = u_t - self.renorm*(self.mu + (self.A @ torch.exp(u).T).T)
    return ode
```

the ODE system to be solve is ∂*t* *ui* = *µ* + *A*⋅exp(*ui*), where *µ* ∈ ℝ^N and *A* ∈ ℝ^(N,N) are stored in the matrix `theta`, are fixed parameters involved in the ODE.

How could I implement the function `dt` so that there is no more loop in it ?
I also tried the decorator `jit` but without success either...